# State government debt in India

Tags: india, budget

I had a look at the Delhi Government Budget for the year 2019-20 (see here: http://prsindia.org/parliamenttrack/budgets/delhi-budget-analysis-2019-20), and was wondering about the composition of the borrowing component.

Can state and UT governments issue bonds? Or do they borrow only from banks, and not from the general public?

Answer (score 3):

To give you a simple answer Yes!
State govt can issues bonds and are publicly traded on [BSE](https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/securitylist_cg.aspx?Type=S).
Here are specifically Delhi issued bonds. Not sure how authenticated are these at [IndiaMart](https://dir.indiamart.com/delhi/investment-service.html).